# Image in Sphinx without html link

Tags: image, hyperlink, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How can I simply prevent automatic link on images in a Sphinx/reStructuredText, which are using `:scale:` attribute? The documentation is exported as HTML, and I would like the image not to be clickable. I want reduce them in size for better document readability and it would be simpler to adjust the size with `:scale:` attribut rather than image editions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [html_scaled_image_link](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_scaled_image_link) configuration option can be used to globally turn on/off this behaviour.

Authors can override this for individual images with:

- the :target: option and an URL, if the generic setting is False,
- the :class: option with value `no-scaled-link`, if the generic setting is True (since Sphinx 3.0).